# Do I need both cache-control and expires on my images hosted on amazon s3?

Tags: browser, caching, amazon-s3, webbrowser-control, amazon-web-services

I've recently switched to hosting the images for my site onto s3, and when i upload images to s3 i add this metatag :

"Cache-Control=public,max-age=2593000"

when I run yslow, it tells me the images have no far-flung expiry date (Expires metatag).

Do I have to add an Expires entry too ? I've searched quite a bit and it seems you really only need one or the other, but I couldn't find anything conclusive. I don't like that my yslow score has fallen :)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the Expires tag along with Cache-Control. It's not going to hurt anything, and you'll be covered for more cases. Including, apparently, yslow.

Answer (score 0):

[The Amazon docs say](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html):

> After the expiration date and time in the Expires header passes, CloudFront gets the object again from the origin server every time an edge location receives a request for the object.
>
> We recommend that you use the Cache-Control max-age directive instead of the Expires header field to control object caching. If you specify values both for Cache-Control max-age and for Expires, CloudFront uses only the value of max-age.